# Pandas handling of daylight saving time (double hour) excel / csv compatible

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading / writing quarter-hourly data into a csv file. The csv file format is given, since it is processed by Excel.

CSV looks like this:

```
from;Price
...
30.10.2022 01:00;120,41
30.10.2022 01:15;104,2
30.10.2022 01:30;89,93
30.10.2022 01:45;71,21
30.10.2022 02:00;101,54
30.10.2022 02:15;92,1
30.10.2022 02:30;88,38
30.10.2022 02:45;80,83
30.10.2022 02:00;100,64  <-- Double Hour
30.10.2022 02:15;91,2    <-- Double Hour
30.10.2022 02:30;87,49   <-- Double Hour
30.10.2022 02:45;83,3    <-- Double Hour
30.10.2022 03:00;86,45
30.10.2022 03:15;83,94
30.10.2022 03:30;90,12
30.10.2022 03:45;87,86
...
```

My process is:

- read_csv into df
- pull new data from an api and format into a dict
- cast dict into a new df (appending_df)
- Sort df based on index
- append and drop duplicates based on the timeseries index `df = df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='last')]`

This works well, unless there is a shift from daylight saving time to regular time. The double hour is simply droped, because I drop duplicats. Even if would not need to drop duplicates, the sorting action would sort the double hour differently. Inserting into the index, instead of appending, wouldn't work either, because of the duplicate index entries.

Normally, I would cast the time into UTC and use +2 and +1 to differentiate between summer/winter, but the timestamps in the csv are timezone argnostic and Excel does not know about timezones.

How could I handle the csv import? How would I make Pandas know the difference between the first and the second hour in the timeseries? And how would I handle the appending / insertion action?

Here is my code so far:

```
USE_PKL = False
DATE_FORMAT = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'
# Define the file paths for the report and the url endpoint
pricing_file = Path(r'//...PATH...') / 'exaa_spot_quarterly.csv'
pricing_pkl = Path(r'//...PATH...') / 'exaa_spot_quarterly.zip'


def load_old_data():

    # Load the old data to append / update. USE_PKL specifies weather the .csv or the .pkl should be used. 
    try:
        if USE_PKL: 
            df = pd.read_pickle(filepath_or_buffer=pricing_pkl, compression='infer')
        else: 
            df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=pricing_file, delimiter=';', header=0, index_col=0, decimal=",")
            df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format=DATE_FORMAT)
        
    except:
        df = pd.DataFrame()
    return(df)

def save_data(df):
    # Save DataFrame to PKL and CSV
    df.to_pickle(path=pricing_pkl, compression='infer')
    df.to_csv(path_or_buf=pricing_file, sep=";", index=True, index_label='von', encoding="ANSI", decimal=",", date_format=DATE_FORMAT)

def load_api_data():

    # Prepare the requests Session 
    s = requests.Session()
    data = {}

    # Pull data from EXAA Website and format into dict
    for offset in range(0, 2):
        onDate = (date.today() - timedelta(days=offset))
        print (onDate)
        
        url = (f'https://www.exaa.at/data/trading-results?delivery_day={onDate.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")}&market=de&auction=grey')
        resp = s.get(url)
        quarterly_data = resp.json()["data"]["q"]

        for i in quarterly_data:
            timestamp = datetime.strptime(i["AuctionDay"],'%Y-%m-%d')
            parsed_regex = re.search("^Q(\d\d)_(\d)$",i["Product"])
            timestamp_hour = int(parsed_regex.group(1)) - 1 
            timestamp_minute = (int(parsed_regex.group(2)) - 1) * 15
            timestamp = timestamp.replace(hour=timestamp_hour, minute=timestamp_minute)
            data[timestamp] = float(i["Price"])
    return(data)


df = load_old_data()
data = load_api_data()

# Append the data from EEX / dict to the old DataFrame
appending_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index', columns=['Preis'])
df = df.append(appending_df)
df = df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
save_data(df)
```